# the logs do not appear in Kibana even if it exist on the cluster of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, clustered-index

Please, Can you give me yours suggestions about this problem ?

I have the indexed logs which arrive up to the cluster of elasticsearch, on the other hand, they do not appear in Kibana either in their TAGS or without their TAGS.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to do in Kibana? Let's say you are trying to make a histogram, then what are you using as the X-axis ?

I had a similar problem. My data was getting added to the Elasticsearch index but it was not getting visualized in kibana. It just said "no results found" no matter what I did. Then I discovered that I had a problem with the timestamp field that I was using as X-axis.

More specifically, the data arriving at the elasticsearch index had the current GMT+2 timestamp but kibana was configured with UTC time. So, kibana was configured to visualize data received in the last hours BUT the data that was arriving had a timestamp that was 2 hours AHEAD of the current time according to UTC.